# AES vs AESWrap, how are they related?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I want to add cryptography to my program and after some research on cypher algorithms i found about AES and AESWrap and my main question is, how are they related? To be honest i don't realy understand the whole process since i've never used crryptography before. At first i thought that AESWrap was the AES's decription key but it's something more than that.

I am developing a chat program in java and i want to encrypt the streams of String, so basically any outside attacker unless he knows the algorithm's process and the keys from server and client he can't get access to the stream. I thought of using Blowfish but from papers i read it appears that even though it's fast it has some problems in its rounds. Now i am digressing so to sum it all up, do i "have to" use AESWrap with AES or are those two completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AESWrap** is an algorithm describing a way to encrypt encryption keys. You don't need to use AESWrap to use **AES**. You might use **AESWrap** if you need to encrypt the encryption key.

If you are developing a chat program, why not use **SSL/TLS** to secure the communication? Using symmetric key algorithms (alone) like **AES** gives the problem of distributing the keys to both ends. A problem **SSL/TLS** solves by use of certificates.

Comment: I was thinking of using Diffie–Hellman key exchange method to make the server and client create a common key afterwards. In my belief i think with this way i can limit the ways a "hacker" can gain access since he must know both client's and server's keys in order to find the common one created afterwards.